# Is it possible to fulfill a promise when any promise has completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an array of urls that I want to make a web request for. I want to call the web request asynchronously with promises, and continue the chain for any promise which has completed. Right now I am doing

```
.then((lines) => {
    var tasks = [];
    lines.forEach((line) => {
        tasks.push(() => { return rp(BASE_URL + line); });
    });
    return Promise.map(tasks, (job) => { return job(); }, { concurrency: 5 });
})
.then((info) => {
    inspect('info: ' + info);
})
```

However, the issue with this is that it waits for ALL tasks to complete before calling the next `.then()`

I am wondering if it possible to call .then() for any task which has been resolved and continue the chain?

I am guessing I could do something like:

```
.then((lines) => {
    lines.forEach((line) => {
        rp(BASE_URL + line)
            .then((info) => {
                inspect(info);
            });
    });
})
.then((a) => {
    // all requests have been made
})
```

This begins something like callback hell as I am nesting my .then()'s and will probably need to do so in a few other cases where I encounter the same problem.

What I am looking for is something like:

```
.then((lines) => {
    lines.forEach((line) => {
        yield return rp(BASE_URL + line);
    });
})
.then((info) => {
    // will call inspect on each yield
    inspect('info: ' + info);
})
```

Comment: You could implement your own type of promise. Maybe name it `PromiseGroup` or `PromiseList`. An object of that type would then represent an arbitrary number of promises. Then you may write e.g. `PromiseGroup(lines).then(line => rp(BASE_URL + line)).then(info => inspect('info: ' + info))`

Comment: Your "callback hell" version is correct. Promises stop you from having to keep nesting indent levels for multiple callbacks, but if you need to do things not at the "top level" of the chain, nested promises are fine

Comment: After seeing Benjamin's solution I have to say that Observables look like a great solution. So maybe you could have a function called `arrayToObservable` or something like that to convert `lines` into an observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array of urls that I want to make a web request for. I want to call the web request asynchronously with promises, and continue the chain for any promise which has completed.

How would you do it in synchronous code? Promises emulate synchronous code.

You'd put the logic of processing a *whole* single request in a function and then `map` on that:

```
.map(processLine);

function processLine(line) {
    return rp(BASE_URL + line).then(inspect);
}
```

It's important to understand that this is not an artifact but a core property of the promise proxy model. Promises represent singular tasks like callbacks - and not plural tasks like event emitters.

You might want to consider an observable or a more reactive system if you're interested, you can also use async iterators (effectively your "desired" syntax). I use observables since they're easier to use here, but both would work:

```
new Observable(obs => {
   let reqs = lines.map(x => rp(BASE_URL + line));
   let counter = reqs.length;
   for(let req of reqs) {
       req.then(v => { 
          obs.onNext(v);
          if(!--counter) obs.onCompleted();
       });
   }
}).map(u => { // every new value is available here
    console.log(u); // use flatMap and return a promise if you want 
                    // promise like chaining behavior
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(!--counter)` or `if(--counter === 0)`?

Comment: Good catch, should probably be `Observable.from(lines).map(x => rp(BASE_URL + line)).flatMap(x => x)` instead of that explicit construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can tidy up your callback hell version a bit, using [.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/map.html) and [.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/each.html) to reduce some of the nesting level

```
.map((line) => {
    return rp(BASE_URL + line);
}, {concurrency: 5})
.each((info) =>
    inspect(info);
})
.then((a) => {
    // all requests have been made
})
```

Note that this does behave a little bit differently to your version. The `.each` callback will only run after all the requests are done. Moving to a stream-based processing model could avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Your "callback hell" is not hell at all, but rather an elegant way to run multiple asynchronous chains in parallel, something there is no synchronous equivalent of.

You're missing a critical `return` in your version however - why I've come to adore the implicit return of arrow functions sans `{}` - and you left out the mapping.

In es6 I'd do:

```
.then(lines => Promise.all(lines.map(line =>
    rp(BASE_URL + line).then(info => inspect(info)))));
})
.then(allInspectResults => {
    // all requests and inspections have been made
})
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: this seems to suffer from the basic issue I am trying to avoid. If rp() takes a long time, but I need the result from that to then go issue another blocking call, and then I need the result from that to issue another blocking call, and so on, then I have to wait for ALL of a to be done before I can call b, and then wait for ALL of b to be done before I can call c, etc.. I need to be able to call b(a) the moment one of the items for a is done.

Comment: `rp` is asynchronous, right? Then there is no blocking. Say there are 5 lines, then `rp()` will be called 5 times one after the other, and hopefully each call returns immediately and then the `inspect` call is tacked on immediately, until you have 5 promises. From this point on, the only thing that waits for all 5 things to finish is `allInspectResults`. Each of the 5 `inspect` calls depend only on the promise from the corresponding `rp` call, and the order they'll get called in depends on which `rp` calls finish first. The asynchronous part of the `rp` calls are running in parallel.